# pytest-xdist results in AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'style'

Tags: pytest, allure, xdist, pytest-xdist

Currently using allure-pytest-adaptor 1.7.8, pytest 3.2.1 and pytest-xdist 1.20.0

Having the issue when I use the xdist to run tests in parallel, if I ran tests all in serial, no such issue:

If there is only 1 or no failures, allure report is able to get generated

When there are more than one failures in a test run, allure report cannot be generated, stack trace and error messages:

```
 File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/bin/py.test", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 58, in main
    return config.hook.pytest_cmdline_main(config=config)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 745, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 339, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 334, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 614, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 139, in pytest_cmdline_main
    return wrap_session(config, _main)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 133, in wrap_session
    exitstatus=session.exitstatus)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 745, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 339, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 334, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 613, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 250, in _wrapped_call
    wrap_controller.send(call_outcome)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/terminal.py", line 406, in pytest_sessionfinish
    outcome.get_result()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 279, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 265, in __init__
    self.result = func()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 614, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/pytest_plugin.py", line 494, in pytest_sessionfinish
    self.impl._write_xml(f, s)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/common.py", line 254, in _write_xml
    xmlfied.toxml(),
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 129, in toxml
    manys = sum([[(m[0], v) for v in m[1]] for m in entries(Many)], [])
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 123, in entries
    for (name, rule) in items
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    if isinstance(rule, clazz) and rule.check(getattr(self, name))]
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 109, in value
    values = super(WrappedMany, self).value(name, what)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 103, in value
    return [self.rule.value(name, x) for x in what]
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 103, in <listcomp>
    return [self.rule.value(name, x) for x in what]
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 92, in value
    return what.toxml()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 128, in toxml
    nested = entries(Nested)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 123, in entries
    for (name, rule) in items
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    if isinstance(rule, clazz) and rule.check(getattr(self, name))]
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 92, in value
    return what.toxml()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 126, in toxml
    elements = entries(Element)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 123, in entries
    for (name, rule) in items
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
    if isinstance(rule, clazz) and rule.check(getattr(self, name))]
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/rules.py", line 80, in value
    return element_maker(self.name or name, self.namespace)(legalize_xml(unicodify(what)))
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/allure/utils.py", line 126, in unicodify
    return text_type(something)  # @UndefinedVariable
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 694, in __str__
    s = self.__unicode__()
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 704, in __unicode__
    self.toterminal(tw)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 735, in toterminal
    element[0].toterminal(tw)
  File "/data/jenkins/workspace/Pilot_WebUI_Python_Functional_Test/automated-tests/.tox/jenkins-webui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 764, in toterminal
    if entry.style == "long":
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue using:

- Python 2.7.10
- allure-pytest-adaptor 1.7.9
- pytest 3.0.0
- pytest-xdist 1.20.0

I found this link but am not able to upgrade the plugins and my Python version at present:

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/2811

If the above works for you great but if you find yourself in need of a patch to the problem you are having I have one that may be of use.

The problem (I think) is the way xdist failures interact with pytest and the pytest-allure-adaptor plugin. Combined they send failure output as a dict and not a class object, which the pytest failure `ReprTraceback` class uses to work with failure output data.

This can be solved by storing test report attributes in an object using the `__dict__` object. It turns out that the author already partially addressed this.  I simply updated the existing method within the allure `pytest_plugin.py` to expose all necessary report data then replaced the intended report finalizer conditionals with the updated method. I have a patch here from a forked version of the plugin:

https://github.com/weeksghost/allure-python/tree/parallel-test-results

I'm sure there are better ways to handle this but it looks like this version of the allure project is no longer supported in favor of an updated version which I feel is a pretty awesome upgrade. I will be upgrading but at my own pace hence the hack.

I hope this is helpful.